# python ctypes - access dll with minor missing imports

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, dlopen, python-c-extension

I am trying to access custom C++ DLL from python via ctypes' WinDLL. This DLL references to other DLLs where one of these has a minor, optional and hence unimportant import of a Windows 8 DLL which is not available on my Windows 7 system. The code I want to access from python does not require this optional import. Yet, a

```
import ctypes
ctypes.WinDLL('pathToDLL')
```

results in a:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
      self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

This is on Windows 7 with Python 3.4.

If I understand the function of dlopen correctly, the default behaviour of dlopen on Windows is RTLD_NOW. The documentation says that the **mode** argument is not supported on Windows.  [Neither is sys.setdlopenflags()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html).

There are some other threads with respect to Mac OS X and Linux. Yet nothing for Windows.

But dlopen seems to be hardwired to RTLD_NOW, see [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l1311).

Any idea anyone?

PS:

1. My ctypes method works with a second DLL without the optional import.
2. This DLL is only available in binary format. Recompilation is therefore not an option.
3. The missing DLL is some Windows Help DLL which is linked from MSHTML.dll. I checked with DependencyWalker. This is not needed for my code.

Comment: On Windows, ctypes calls `LoadLibrary`. It could call `LoadLibraryEx` to allow passing flags via the otherwise unused `mode` parameter. But that's not going to help you here, since there's no flag to force delay loading of static DLL imports. That's a [linker option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx).